# Updating progress bar in Tkinter simultaneously while recording audio Python3

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, pyaudio

My goal for this simple program is to be able to show a progress bar of time the mic has been recording(range from 0 - 30 seconds). I am using the Tkinter library, Python 3.6, and PyAudio to record.

I finished writing the code for the individual parts(recording + updating progress bar) but I don't know how to change the code so that they happen at the same time(not one after the other). Also, I've realized that while I am recording, the GUI freezes(I can't click or resize buttons), I am also wondering about how to fix this issue. After doing some more research, I have a feeling that the answer lies with multi-threading or root.update() but I am not sure.

I am looking for a code example of recording audio **while** I simultaneously update the progress bar.

Here is an example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)  # for reproducibility
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')  # No pictures displayed


class Test_GUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        root = self

        label_title = Label(root, text="Progress Bar Recording Sample")
        label_title.pack(fil="x")

        topFrame = Frame(root)
        topFrame.pack(side=TOP)

        self.recordButton = Button(topFrame, text="Record", command=self.start)
        self.recordButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(topFrame, orient="horizontal",
                                        length=200, mode="determinate")
        self.min = 0
        self.maxMin = 0
        self.progress.pack(side=RIGHT)

        # recording attributes.
        self.CHUNK = 1024
        self.FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
        self.CHANNELS = 2
        self.RATE = 44100
        self.RECORD_SECONDS = 15
        self.WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "/Users/Sree/Desktop/PythonPrograms/audio_output_test.wav"

    def start(self):
        print("here")

        self.progress["value"] = 0
        self.maxMin = 30
        self.progress["maximum"] = 30


        '''
        I need the following 2 lines to happen at the same time
        the progress bar needs to update from 1-30 seconds(which is the time I am recording)
        '''
        self.record()
        self.update_progress() #The progress bar is from 0 sec to 30 sec indicating what percentage of the time the mic has been recording for. 

    def update_progress(self):
        self.min += 0.1
        self.progress["value"] = self.min
        if self.min < self.maxMin:
            # update after 100 ms
            self.after(100, self.update_progress)

    def record(self):
        p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        stream = p.open(format=self.FORMAT,
                             channels=self.CHANNELS,
                             rate=self.RATE,
                             input=True,
                             frames_per_buffer=self.CHUNK)

        print("* recording")

        frames = []

        for i in range(0, int(self.RATE / self.CHUNK * self.RECORD_SECONDS)):
            data = stream.read(self.CHUNK)
            frames.append(data)

        print("* done recording")

        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        p.terminate()

        wf = wave.open(self.WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
        wf.setnchannels(self.CHANNELS)
        wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(self.FORMAT))
        wf.setframerate(self.RATE)
        wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
        wf.close()


app = Test_GUI()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: tkinter doesn't *"play well"* with multithreaded programs. So whilst I'm sure this is possibly, it's not likely to be easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent the GUI from freezing while recording, you need to launch the recording in a separate thread. To do so, you can use the  [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module for instance and replace `self.record()` in your `start` method by:

```
record_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.record, daemon=True)
record_thread.start()
```

Comment: Thanks this solution worked for me! Just wondering do I ever need to stop the new thread, by doing something like record_thread.stop() or will it automatically be destroyed once the recording is finished.

Comment: @SreehariR I don't think you need to stop the thread, it just dies once the recording is finished.